# Creating an instance of collection in JAVA

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should the interface for a Java class be prefered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147468/why-should-the-interface-for-a-java-class-be-prefered)
>   [What is the benefit of polymorphism using Collection interface to create ArrayList object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356113/what-is-the-benefit-of-polymorphism-using-collection-interface-to-create-arrayli)

I see in many examples that when one creates an instance of some collection like TreMap, he uses it's base as type:

```
Map<String,String> theMap = new TreeMap<String,String>();
```

Why not to use

```
TreeMap<String,String> theMap = new TreeMap<String,String>();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should the interface for a Java class be prefered?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147468/why-should-the-interface-for-a-java-class-be-prefered), [What is the benefit of polymorphism using Collection interface to create ArrayList object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356113/what-is-the-benefit-of-polymorphism-using-collection-interface-to-create-arrayli), [List versus ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062982/list-versus-arraylist) and possibly more.

Comment: It is very good that you are asking. Some people do not understand this and do not ask and write concrete classes in the left part of assignment. Doing this is a crime.

Answer (score 5):

Because it's considered a better practice to code to the *interface* (Map) instead of the *implementation* (TreeMap).  This way you are free to switch to a different implementation (e.g. HashMap, if you later decide it is a better solution) with minimal code touch-points.

Comment: nobody can explain better. But you mean "e.g. HashMap" in this case.

Comment: @AlexR: fixed it, thanks for pointing out that error.

Answer (score 3):

It's generally better to code to an interface, not an implementation, which allows an implementation change without having to change code that refers to it.

The only time it's reasonable to *not* do this is when code *relies* on characteristics of a specific implementation. For example, if the code requires the fast indexed list item access `ArrayList` provides, it might make sense to force a specific implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is better to program against `Interfaces` because it is easier, e. g., to switch from TreeMap (ordered) to HashMap (maybe faster).

If you use interfaces when possible, you only have to change one sourcecode part.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Directly quoted what was said.

> Let q(x) be a property provable about objects x of type T. Then q(y) should be provable for objects y of type S where S is a subtype of T.

**Simple explanation**

- `Map` is an `interface`
- And an `interface` is a contract

While using a `Map` we confirms that, we are using the contract of what a `Map` is supposed to do.

**For example**

1. `doSomething(Map<String, String> map)`
2. `doSomething(TreeMap<String, String> map)`

`doSomething(Map<String, String> map)` gives option to use any implementation which confirm the contract of `Map` allowing any of its subtype to work.

Whether `doSomething(TreeMap<String, String> map)` accepts any subtype of `TreeMap`. But `TreeMap` is not a contract so any subtype of `TreeMap` can violates its signature/behavior(methods actually). Thus making `TreeMap` less preferable compare to `Map`. [Composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) can give u more idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of java best pratices: program using interfaces if you can.

This helps to make you application more flexible because the method that receives this Map can also work on the other implementations of Map, but the method that received TreeMap can only use TreeMap and it's childrens.

So you get freedom to modify your method workings if you latter find that a HashMap would improve your application speed.