# Advantage of Collection over an ArrayList

Tags: java, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the benefit of polymorphism using Collection interface to create ArrayList object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356113/what-is-the-benefit-of-polymorphism-using-collection-interface-to-create-arrayli)

what is the advantage of defining an Arraylist as
`Collection<User> parameterGroupList = new ArrayList<User>()` over `ArrayList<User> parameterGroupList = new ArrayList<User>();`

Comment: `Collection` is an interface (with no guarantee over runtime bounds and some optional methods). [What else implement it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)?

Comment: design to interfaces, effective java

Comment: The "interesting" (fsvo) question to me, would be, when to use a `Collection` over a `List`?

Comment: @user1831612 please search for similar questions before posting duplicates!!

Comment: You're more likely to see methods taking `Collection` _arguments_ -- allowing you to pass a `List` or a `Set` or whatever -- than you are to see variables actually declared as `Collection`.

Answer (score 0):

If the static type `parameterGroupList` is `Collection<User>`, the users of `parameterGroupList` will only use the operations available in `Collection<User>` and avoid  the operations specific to `ArrayList`. As a result, it makes it easier for you to replace `ArrayList` to some other collection like `LinkedList` in future.

Answer (score -1):

Simply putting same as the advantage of using **Runtime Polymorphism.**

What you are asking is Java 101 question.