# Difference between Collection and Arraylist in Java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [What is the benefit of polymorphism using Collection interface to create ArrayList object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356113/what-is-the-benefit-of-polymorphism-using-collection-interface-to-create-arrayli)

```
 ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
 Collection c=new ArrayList();
```

What is difference between object `al` and `c`? Are both of them are same or what?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Collections API is a set of classes and interfaces that support operations on collections of objects.

Example of classes: HashSet, HashMap, ArrayList, LinkedList, TreeSet and TreeMap.
Example of interfaces: Collection, Set, List and Map.

Whereas,
ArrayList: It is re-sizable array implementation. Belongs to 'List' group in collection. It permits all elements, including null. It is not thread -safe.

Collections: It implements Polymorphic algorithms which operate on collections.

Collection: It is the root interface in the collection hierarchy.

**The following** interfaces (collection types) extends the Collection interface:

- List
- Set
- SortedSet
- NavigableSet
- Queue
- Deque

Java does not come with a usable implementation of the Collection interface, so you will have to use one of the listed subtypes. The Collection interface just defines a set of methods (behaviour) that each of these Collection subtypes share. This makes it possible ignore what specific type of Collection you are using, and just treat it as a Collection. This is standard inheritance, so there is nothing magical about, but it can still be a nice feature from time to time.

Comment: This is in my opinion not an answer to the "trivial question". It does not explain why the objects al and c are fundamentally different.

Answer (score 5):

The second is [coding to interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970806/coding-to-interfaces).  It allows the `ArrayList` to be swapped for another `Collection` (e.g. `Vector` or `TreeSet`) without any side effects.

Answer (score 3):

Same object is created, but reference is different.

So in second case you can work with your `ArrayList` only as if it is just `Collection`, unless casting.

Comment: "The question is too easy", but only this answer hits the core of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

`Collection` is an [Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Collection.html). Look at the methods.

`List` [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) has methods to access by index. List also extends `Collection` interface.

`ArrayList` is a concrete implementation that implements `List` interface. ArrayList

What you are doing is some abstraction.

If you do :

```
Collection foo = new ArrayList();
```

you wont have access to `List` interface methods. such as accessing with index.

Answer (score 2):

In `al` you are blocked to use only arraylists. You can't convert/cast anything but for arraylist.

In `c` you can convert/cast any class which implements the `Collection` interface.