# Difference between instantiating with interface and concrete class? (HashMap,Map & List, ArrayList)

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I know that `List` and `Map` are interfaces that can be implemented and `ArrayList` and `HashMap` are classes whose objects can be created and used.

I know the difference between the two pairs. My actual question is, is there a difference between the following two statements?

```
HashMap< K, V>  myMap = new HashMap<K, V>(); 
Map< K, V> myMap = new HashMap<K, V>();
```

And if there is, then what is the difference and when should I use which one? Similarly, what is the difference between:

```
ArrayList< Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List< Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413543/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-a-interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HashMap< K, V> myMap = new HashMap();
```

is creating a instance of `HashMap`, as you see anywhere in Java.

Whereas:

```
Map< K, V> myMap = new HashMap();
```

is creating a instance of `Map` with a concrete implementation, called as Programming with interfaces.

The second way, i.e [Programming with interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface-based_programming), brings the **modularity**  to your program.

A nice explanation here, about what is the benefits and when to go for it:

[What is the benefit of polymorphism using Collection interface to create ArrayList object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356113/what-is-the-benefit-of-polymorphism-using-collection-interface-to-create-arrayli)

Comment: when should I use which one? which one is best in code design?

Comment: @786  Yes,Always prefer to code with interface.See the link and accepted asnwer.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` is a concrete implementation of `List` interface.

So the difference is in one you have concrete class reference in other you have interface reference.

```
HashMap< K, V>  myMap = new HashMap<K, V>(); //reference of concrete class HashMap
Map< K, V>  myMap = new HashMap<K, V>(); //reference of interface Map
```

***You should always try to program with interfaces***

> NOTE: Program with interfaces should be used when you are *passing* the
>   `Map` somewhere else, for *local variables* you are *free to use* concrete
>   implementation.

Other difference is that on the `Map` one, you won't be able to call methods of `HashMap`

Comment: +1 for You should always try to program with interfaces